# ares_library_init error in Node.js

Tags: node.js, centos, centos5

I have a problem running a simple Hello World on Node.js. I'm using CentOS and installed it via yum. When I run the file with Node.js, this error pops up:

`node: symbol lookup error: node: undefined symbol: ares_library_init`

I tried searching google to no avail. I only found that this belongs to the [c-ares](http://c-ares.haxx.se/) library. Any idea of how I can solve this?

The file contains this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. You can't use yum.

```
yum remove nodejs
git clone http://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
git checkout v0.4.10
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: I had the exact same issue in fedora 16 after following the yum install instructions. removing it and configuring it now from scratch.